# Cobham's characterization of FP

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, polynomial-time

Does anyone know of an accessible introduction to Cobham's model independent characterization of **FP** and it's equivalence to the standard definition using Turing machines?  The best source I could find on-line was https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sacook/homepage/ptime.pdf : a paper by Stephen Bellantoni and Stephen Cook detailing another similar approach.  However, it is a little too difficult for me to understand.

As a side question, does anyone know if researchers are still interested in Cobham's formulation or feel it could possibly lead to resolving open problems?

Comment: I'm not sure how accessible you expect a recursion-theoretic characterization of polynomial time to be. Such things are necessarily very technical and they're difficult to understand because they involve difficult concepts.

Comment: @DavidRicherby  I'm mainly interested in just the basic functions it entails because I know at least that FP is the class closed under certain operations and functions (one I think is called the "smash" function, but I don't know its formal definition).  I guess the equivalence proof will be beyond my reach at this point.